# Oracle Apex: "Type: Hidden" vs "Server-side Condition: Never"

Tags: oracle-apex

Type:
"Hidden:
    Items that are included within the page source but are not rendered. Hidden item values are saved in session state. They are generally used to store values required by page processing or other page items, but should not be displayed to the end user."

Server side condition: 
"Never:
    The component is never rendered."

If an item's type is set to hidden, is it necessary to set the server side condition to never? Or is that superfluous?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the question is just about show or don't show, yes. it's unnecessary!

But a hidden item still existing in the page, it's just not showed to the user. You can see it pressing F12 and checking then in your HTML page. You can use hidden items on pl/sql process, dynamic actions or acessing it with javascript or jquery.

The server side condition remove the item of your HTML page and you can do nothing in these items.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "remove the item", It exists in the meta-data definition. It's just that it never renders.  It's a rare occasion I'll use NEVER http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2013/12/build-option-use-case-replace-condition-never.html